# Why is review queue showing a number when it is empty?

Tags: discussion, support

Very conceivably not the right area to be asking, but since it pertains to what I saw here on this site...

The review menu notification (see below) shows there are 12 items for review.

[image: Non-empty review queue!]

When I click on the link to the review queue, I arrive to find there is nothing for (me to) review (see below). Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The review menu notification number is an estimate, based on cached details; it is not a real-time, up-to-date count.

See Shog9's answer at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266000/review-page-does-not-work-as-before,  or another one at [Does the review queue page show only reviews requiring your action? Does it differ, and when does it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238698/does-the-review-queue-page-show-only-reviews-requiring-your-action-does-it-diff/238699#238699) (thanks to snailboat for digging this one up!)

Comment: Also, it's based on the tasks available to everyone, not to any individual.  The old suggested edit indicator showed an action you could take.  This one doesn't indicate any such thing; it'll be stuck above 10 for everyone the entire time the self-eval is going, since it's impossible to clear that queue.